# Com_Users - Edit ACL - Not allowed (locked)

Tags: administrator, acl

[image: Joomla! users permissions locked]

For some reason, this says **Not Allowed (locked)**

I can change every other user group to allowed and it works.  But not this one.  Even public!  I'm so confused as to why this would be.  I mean, people don't even have to be in the public group to be in the public group.

Why would this be?

Comment: What is your permission level?  Are you a Super User? Administrator?  Are you able to make yourself a Super User?

Comment: Yes I am a super user

Comment: What is `Global Configuration` -> `Public` -> `Configure Options Only`'s "New Setting" value?

Comment: I dont understand the question

Comment: Public value is disallow. But changing it to allow doesn't effect admin. I can change all of the others admin is the only user group that won't change

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nc5zu2z